# SOAP request with XML response and body swift 3, Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xml-parsing, alamofire

I do not find any information about how to send `SOAP` request on swift 3. I have a `SOAP` API with `XML`. I use Alamofire as the net client at my project. My question is How to make `SOAP` request with `XML` on Swift, preferably with Alamofire library.

Comment: try this  : http://blastar.biz/2016/08/09/swift-how-to-consume-soap-using-alamofire/

Comment: Ty, man;) This can be correct answer.

Comment: happy to helping you :)

Comment: @KKRocks  link is not working can you provide the code is possible

Answer (score 3):

I used following libraries

```
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SWXMLHash'
  pod 'AEXML'
  pod 'StringExtensionHTML'
```

Then you need to import

```
import SWXMLHash
import StringExtensionHTML
import AEXML
import Alamofire
```

This function works for me

```
 func getLines(){

        let soapRequest = AEXMLDocument()

        let envelopeAttributes = ["xmlns:soap":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "xmlns:i" :"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance","xmlns:d" : "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","xmlns:c":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/","xmlns:v":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"]

        let act : AEXMLElement = AEXMLElement(name: "n0:getAllStations", value: "", attributes: ["id":"o0","c:root":"1", "xmlns:n0":"http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"])
        let child1 : AEXMLElement = AEXMLElement(name: "lang", value: "en", attributes: ["i:type":"d:string"])

        act.addChild(child1)

        let envelope = soapRequest.addChild(name: "soap:Envelope", attributes: envelopeAttributes)
        envelope.addChild(name :"soap:Header")
        let body = envelope.addChild(name: "soap:Body")
        body.addChild(act)

        let soapLenth = String(soapRequest.xml.characters.count)
        let theURL = URL(string: "http://103.11.35.13:9080/services/RailwayWebServiceV2Proxy.RailwayWebServiceV2ProxyHttpSoap12Endpoint")

        print(soapRequest.xml)

        var mutableR = URLRequest(url: theURL!)
        mutableR.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        mutableR.addValue(soapLenth, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        mutableR.addValue("getAllStations", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
        mutableR.httpMethod = "POST"
        mutableR.httpBody = soapRequest.xml.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        Alamofire.request(mutableR)
            .responseString { response in
                if let xmlString = response.result.value {

                    let xml = SWXMLHash.parse(xmlString)

                    for element in xml["soapenv:Envelope"]["soapenv:Body"]["datas1:lines"]["datas1:line"].all {

                        if let nameElement = element["datas1:id"].element {
                            let line = Lines()
                            line.id = Int(nameElement.text)
                            self.lines.append(line)
                        }

                        if let nameElement = element["datas1:LineName"].element {
                            let line = Lines()
                            line.LineName = nameElement.text
                            self.lines.append(line)
                        }

                    }

                }else{
                    print("error fetching XML")
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Getting errors as "Value of type '[AEXMLElement]' has no member 'compactMap'" .please help.

Answer (score 1):

use this extension to Alamofire.
[AlamofireSoap](https://github.com/ShakeebM/AlamofireSoap)

Comment: @Shakeeb Manjeri is there a feature to add Basic Auth?

Comment: yes, basic/NTLM authentication is supported in alamofire, this is just an extension of alamofire so it will support every feature which supported by Alamofire